# MySQL INSERT INTO not working with python 3.6

Tags: python, mysql

I am using MySQL in python 3.6. I am trying to insert a data into a table, the syntax should be correct since if I try it with other app and it works.

```
    def setgetdata(self,setcommand,getcommand):
    """
    Function will update the database for the given setcommand,
    then will get the data using getcommand and return the data
    """
    if self._connection.connect():
        c = self._connection.get_cursor()
        c.execute(setcommand, multi = True)
        self._connection.commit()
        c.execute(getcommand)
        data = c.fetchall()
        c.close()
        self._connection.close()
        return data
    return None
```

My setcommand and getcommand are below

```
SET_STRING="""START TRANSACTION;
    INSERT INTO blog (author_id,title,create_time) VALUES (1,"StackOverFlow",20182222);
    INSERT INTO blog_detail( blog_id, content ) VALUES ( LAST_INSERT_ID(), "Something...");
    COMMIT;
    """
GET_STRING="""SELECT blog_id FROM blog WHERE blog_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();"""
```

There is no error message, it just did not insert successfully.

Comment: What is your errormessage?

Comment: You cannot execute multiple `INSERT` statements in one go. Separate them out into individual strings and execute them one-by-one

Comment: There is no error message, and it just did not insert success